# How to reliably build a complex java project offline

Tags: java, maven, build

We need my current project to be reasonably portable: run, build, test offline in several different, not connected, environments (no internet access, no software development support software can be installed).

We've tried to make it work with Maven offline mode. This, however, does require the local package cache to be managed and kept in-sync across developmental environments. It has proven to be a major headake.

Is there a way to have dependencies versioned in the same repository as the source code still taking advantage of the repository-based build system like Maven (on the machines that are online)?

Comment: I understand the need to run and test in an offline environment. But why do you need development and build procedures without network connectivity?

Comment: Maven has `offline` mode that migh be what you need: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: Tightening the build-test-deploy loop: we're developing against an undocumented legacy system that's only available offline (and in several slightly different instances). Whanna swap the job ;) ?

Comment: Are you using a repository manager ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, nope. We can't even have a versioned control system installed.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your whole intention. The question is: Do you need to make a deployment kind of operation onto your target system which runs the application. The application is being built on another system where you have version control and a build system like Maven plus repository manager etc. available ? Doing development / building on a system where you don't be allowed to use a version control system etc. does not make sense to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could configure Maven local repository as a separate folder in your project. In this case both your source code and a separate folder for Maven local repo will be stored in your version control system. But you will have to manually delete old dependencies in case of version upgrade just not to store unused jars in version control system. There is an option to pass path to local repo as a parameter like this:

```
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=<path>
```

Comment: Do you know the way to make this value default for the repo, but not for the machine?

Comment: You may create settings.xml with all common information (like local repository, remote repositories, etc) and add that file to version control system and use it for your Maven build

Comment: The value in `settings.xml` is machine-specific, not repository specific, right?

Comment: Unfortunately settings.xml it doesn't support relative path to localRepo but looks like it might support environmental variables (as default value for local repo is `${user.home}/.m2/repository/`). So I see 2 options: use environmental property in settings.xml and ask everybody before using Maven to set up that property property to projects directory or do not use that property and ask to edit settings.xml directly to set localRepo